# Zooming to coordinates upon start up using Potree?

Tags: point-cloud, potree

I am using the latest version of Potree (the version last updated 27/08/2018).  I have converted my source LAZ data into Potree compatible LAZ tiles (using PotreeConverter.exe).  I have huge amounts of data (by this I mean possibly a few TBs worth of LAZ data).  This is for the road network of the country I reside in.

How do I programatically zoom to a given set of coordinates (XYZ) in the point cloud upon initial load?

My point cloud is potentially hundreds of miles wide, therefore I need to zoom to given coordinates e.g. XYZ coordinates 409200.000, 209200.000, 150.000.

I have tried the following.  It zooms, not to the desired location/coordinates:

```
Potree.loadPointCloud("pointclouds/OsgbColour/cloud.js", "OsgbColour", e => {
        let pointcloud = e.pointcloud;
        let material = pointcloud.material;
        viewer.scene.addPointCloud(pointcloud);
        material.pointColorType = Potree.PointColorType.RGB; // any Potree.PointColorType.XXXX 
        material.size = 1;
        material.pointSizeType = Potree.PointSizeType.ATTENUATED;
        material.shape = Potree.PointShape.CIRCLE;
        viewer.fitToScreen();

        viewer.scene.view.position.set(409200.000, 290200.000, 150.000);
        viewer.scene.view.lookAt(4092000.000, 290200.000, 150.000);
        var myactivecamera = viewer.scene.getActiveCamera();
        myactivecamera.position.set(4092000.000, 290200.000, 150.000);
        myactivecamera.zoom += 3.0;
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to sort it, as follows (the last 2 lines):

```
Potree.loadPointCloud("pointclouds/OsgbColour/cloud.js", "OsgbColour", e => {
    let pointcloud = e.pointcloud;
    let material = pointcloud.material;
    viewer.scene.addPointCloud(pointcloud);
    material.pointColorType = Potree.PointColorType.RGB; // any Potree.PointColorType.XXXX
    material.size = 1;
    material.pointSizeType = Potree.PointSizeType.ATTENUATED;
    material.shape = Potree.PointShape.CIRCLE;

    viewer.scene.view.position.set(409600.000, 290000.000, 400.000);
    viewer.scene.view.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(409200.000, 290400.000, 75.000));
});
```